# Alterar estilo de palavra ao lado via css

Tags: html5, css3, text

Recebi uma faixa para fazer no layout de um site e gostaria de saber se poderia reproduzir o efeito via css.

Por exemplo tenho a frase -> Olá sou um texto.
Gostaria de conseguir deixar sempre a última palavra do texto em negrito. É possível fazer isso com css? Caso não seja qual seria a melhor forma?

[image: Faixa de exemplo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que é possível existem várias maneiras para isso, vou postar algumas:

usando a tag B, por exemplo seu texto em html -> `<h1> meu texto <b>aqui!</b></h1>`
o texto aqui! ficará em negrito

mas como boas praticas o ideal é usar o css criando um classe:

A propriedade "font-weight", que é o "bold".

O bold equivale a nossa famosa tag , para simplesmente negritar um trecho.
A sintaxe é:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

O negrito serve, basicamente, para destacar um trecho de um texto.
Por exemplo, para fazer a seguinte frase em negrito:

"O CSS é uma linguagem de estilo realmente importante na criação de sites."

Podemos usar o seguinte trecho de código, diretamente na tag :

"O CSS é uma linguagem de estilo `<span style="font-weight: bold">realmente</span>` importante na criação de sites."

Ou criando uma classe em css e depois atribuindo ela a um elemento

```
.negrito {
 font-weight: bold;
}

<span class='negrito'>oi</span>
```

Comment: Obrigado Julio :D É que assim o título que eu to fazendo ele é gerado automaticamente através de uma variável vinda do sistema. Por isso que eu queria conseguir pegar a última palavra, pois a última sempre deveria ficar em negrito. Você acha que dá ?

Comment: da sim, não tem como gerar esse texto ja com as tags?

Comment: qual tecnologia voce está utilizando para back-end

Comment: Está sendo gerado via php

Comment: Consegui resolver via JS (JQuery).

Dessa forma aqui ->
**No HTML**
<h1 class="lastWord">Faixa Simples</h1>

**No css**
.lastWord{
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.wordbold{
 font-weight: bold;
}

**No JS**
$(".lastWord").html(function(){
  var text= $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
  var last = text.pop();
  return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? " <span class='wordbold'>" + last + "</span>" : last);
});

Com isso ele cria um elemento (span) E eu consigo aplicar a sua primeira explicação alterando o estilo dele. Mas também pensando na semântica.

Comment: sim, era com isso mesmo que eu iria postar a solução

Comment: boa mano! trim ótima lógica